# How to access an array index of an Object instance

Tags: java

Good day!

I am wondering How can I access an array index of an Object instance.

My code is as follows:

```
public class PokerPlayer {

    private String name = null;
    private Card [] cardsOnHand = new Card[5]; 

    //getter and setter
}
```

What i want is to access the cardsOnHandArray[index] so that i can call it on another class and set the values per index...

```
public class PokerGame {
      public static void main (String [] Args){
      PokerPlayer players []= new PokerPlayer[4];
      for(PokerPlayer player : players){
          for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
            //ACCESS cardsOnHand index i and store something on it...
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated. How can i also improve my OO design? Thank you in advance

Comment: You should really avoid magic numbers, maybe get rid of 'i<5' and get the value from the Card array, i.e 'i<player.getCardsOnHand.length'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class PokerPlayer {
...
public Card getCard(int index) {
  return this.cardsOnHand[index];
}

public void setCard(int index, Card card) {
  this.cardsOnHand[index] = card;
}
...
}
```

then use:

```
player.getCard(i);
player.setCard(i,new Card());
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost have it. Just call this inside your inner loop:

```
cardsOnHand[i] = new Card();
```

Of course, change what is being assigned to the array according to your requirements.

Comment: but i want to store something in the array cardsOnHand [5]

Comment: There is no such thing as `cardsOnHand[5]` if the length of the array is 5. The index values would be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Answer (score 1):

you can do as:

```
for(PokerPlayer player : players){
          for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
            Card[] cards= player[i].getCardsOnHand();
            cards[i] = new Card();
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public class PokerGame {
  public static void main (String [] Args){
  PokerPlayer players []= new PokerPlayer[4];
  for(PokerPlayer player : players){
      for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
        Card card = player.cardsOnHand[i];
      }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since your `cardsOnHand` array is private, you have to use your (unprovided) setter function.
Which could be something like

```
public void setCard(int index, Card value){
   cardsOnHand[index] = value;
}
```

And in used in your loop as
`player.setCard(i, something)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `PokerPlayer` has a getter for the `cardsOnHand` array:

```
public class PokerGame {
      public static void main (String [] Args){
      PokerPlayer players []= new PokerPlayer[4];
      for(PokerPlayer player : players){
          for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
                player.getCardsOnHand()[i] = new Card();
          }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I think that a better solution is to add a method

```
public void setCard(Card card, int index) {
    assert index < 5;
    cardOnHands[index] = card
}
```

to your `PokerPlayer`.